# Replacing objects in one array to another array, randomly. Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, random, set

Two arrays

```
let array1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]

let array2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
```

I want to choose an index from array2 and replace the object in array1 at the same index with the object from array2. For example

```
array1[3] = array2[3] //["A","B","C","d","E","F","G"]
```

I want to do this randomly, for example

```
let randomIndex: Int = Int(arc4random()) % (array2.count)
```

I want to do this in a 'for' loop until all the indices and objects for array2 are used, but I DON'T WANT TO REPEAT a randomIndex.

If I decrement the number of objects after each iteration, I still could get the same random index. If I use a Set of indices, and remove the used index, I lose my 'orderedness' (if that's a word).

So I seem to be stuck. BTW swift 4's .randomElement won't work on an array of Strings.

Any thoughts?

```
for object in array2 {

  let randomIndex: Int = Int(arc4random()) % (array2.count)
  array1[randomIndex] = array2[randomIndex]
  array2.remove(at: randomIndex)
  }
```

The above does NOT work as I desire. When the object is removed, a new order is established, and I can't replace the object in array1 at the appropriate index.

I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing it. I'm using Swift 4.2.

Comment: Try this: let randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random()) % (array2.count) ; array2.insert(array1[randomNumber], at: randomNumber)

Answer (score 0):

This seems very inefficient, but works:

```
let array1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
let array2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
var array3 = array1                       // ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
var counterSet = Set<Int>()               // empty set

while counterSet.count < array2.count {
  let randomIndex: Int = Int(arc4random()) % (array2.count)    //(16 times)
  counterSet.insert(randomIndex)                               //(16 times)
  array3[randomIndex] = array2[randomIndex]                    //(16 times)
}
counterSet                                // {2, 4, 6, 5, 0, 1, 3}
array3                                    // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

I would still like some input. Thanks Kurt

Answer (score 0):

Do you need shuffled index? If so, the code below does the thing.

```
( 0 ..< array2.count ).shuffled()
```

or

```
Array( stride( from: 0, through: array2.count - 1, by: 1 ) ).shuffled()
```

Comment: I thought of shuffled(), but I need them to NOT be shuffled. They need to stay ordered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
     var array1  = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]

     var array2  = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

    let randomIndex: Int = Int(arc4random()) % (array2.count)
    print("Number:\(randomIndex)")

    array2.insert(array1[randomIndex], at: randomIndex)
    print("array2:\(array2)")
```